# elastic query fails with this error Exception: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Failed to parse query [*/abc*]')

Tags: python, jquery, string, elasticsearch, kibana

The main reason for this error is the selected string starts with / or it includes many of / symbol in it.

Example : "/abc/cd/ef"

It works fine if the selected string does not contain / in it.

This is the query am using:

```
    f1= += ', '+elQuery+' {"query_string" : {"default_field" : "'+eJson+'.string", "query" : "*'+selectedstring+'"}}'+elCb+''
```

When selectedstring is just string it works fine but if it starts with / or it contains /  ...Then the below error is shown.

Example:

```
    ,  {"query_string" : {"default_field" : "abc.ef", "query" : "*/abc*"}}

    Exception: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Failed to parse query [*/abc*]')
```

Here the selectedstring is /abc

Answer (score 0):

you need escaped query string `"*\\/abc*"`

```
 {
    "query_string" : {
        "default_field" : "abc.ef",
        "query" : "*\\/abc*"
    }
 }
```